# Sierpinski Carpet Recursion - Python

Tags: python, recursion

I need some help with a python program. In my CPS II class we went over how to create the sierpinski triangle using recursion. I thought this was pretty interesting and looking into some more topics online. I have been trying to come up with code to create the sierpinski carpet using recursion. I feel like I am close but can't seem to get it all the way. I have absolutely no clue what the problem is.

And before anyone asks, this is not homework. I am simply trying to understand recursion better by practicing with examples.

Here is my code so far; it only works at depth 1. And then at depth 2 it kind of works but something is wrong.

```
from graphics import *
import sys

def sierpinskiCarpet(points, level, window):

    if level == 0:
        square = Rectangle(points[0], points[1])
        square.draw(window)
    else:
        x_0 = (points[0].getX())
        x_02 = (points[1].getX())
        x_1 = ((points[1].getX())/3)
        x_2 = (((points[1].getX())/3)*2)

        y_0 = (points[0].getY())
        y_02 = (points[1].getY())
        y_1 = ((points[0].getY())/3)
        y_2 = (((points[0].getY())/3)*2)


        top1 = [points[0], Point(x_1, y_2)]
        top2 = [Point(x_1, y_0), Point(x_2, y_2)]
        top3 = [Point(x_2, y_0), Point(x_02, y_2)]

        med1 = [Point(x_0, y_2), Point(x_1, y_1)]
        med3 = [Point(x_2, y_2), Point(x_02, y_1)]

        bottom1 = [Point(x_0, y_1), Point(x_1, y_02)]
        bottom2 = [Point(x_1, y_1), Point(x_2, y_02)]
        bottom3 = [Point(x_2, y_1), points[1]]


        sierpinskiCarpet(top1, level - 1, window)
        sierpinskiCarpet(top2, level - 1, window)
        sierpinskiCarpet(top3, level - 1, window)
        sierpinskiCarpet(med1, level - 1, window)
        sierpinskiCarpet(med3, level - 1, window)
        sierpinskiCarpet(bottom1, level - 1, window)
        sierpinskiCarpet(bottom2, level - 1, window)
        sierpinskiCarpet(bottom3, level - 1, window)


def main():
    #get the depth from the system arguemtns
    depth = int(sys.argv[1])
    #set up the window using GraphWin
    window = GraphWin('Sierpinski Carpet', 500, 500)
    #set the corrdiantes of the window
    window.setCoords(-0.1, -0.1, 1.1, 1.1)
    #list the starting points for the first square
    points = [Point(0, 1), Point(1, 0)]

    #call the function with the points
    sierpinskiCarpet(points, depth, window)
    #close the window when clicked
    window.getMouse()

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x_1,  x_2, y_1 and y_2 must have both point[0] and point[1] parts in their formula.

```
x_0 = (points[0].getX())
x_02 = (points[1].getX())
x_1 = (((points[0].getX())/3)*2 +  (points[1].getX())/3)
x_2 = (((points[0].getX())/3)   + ((points[1].getX())/3)*2)
```

And of course, same idea from y.

Comment: This is correct. However I found another error. The y value square point assignments need to be changed as well.

      top1 = [points[0], Point(x_1, y_1)]
      top2 = [Point(x_1, y_0), Point(x_2, y_1)]
      top3 = [Point(x_2, y_0), Point(x_02, y_1)]

and 

    bottom1 = [Point(x_0, y_2), Point(x_1, y_02)]
    bottom2 = [Point(x_1, y_2), Point(x_2, y_02)]       
    bottom3 = [Point(x_2, y_2), points[1]]

This is correct. Thank you for your help!